# EF Core 8 does not create migration files anymore

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-8.0

I am at the end with my nerves, since around a month I cannot create any migration files anymore with EF Core 8. Those are the project references for EF Core I have in my `*.csproj` file which I use to `add-migration`.

It did work before, but not anymore. I had on my laptop a branch, with which I created a migration and even with that branch I can't create any migration files anymore.

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="8.0.2" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Abstractions" Version="8.0.2" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="8.0.2">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
</PackageReference>
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="8.0.2" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="8.0.2">
    <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
</PackageReference>
```

What have I done already:

- Added `DesignTimeDbContextFactory`
- Checked if I have correctly configured `ApplicationDbContext` and added `DbSet<>` with the correct model
- I have in `ApplicationDbContext` a empty constructor
- `ApplicationDbContext` is registered in `Program.cs`
- Checked if DB connection is correct and if it is connecting
- Searched with Github Copilot for a solution and told me that there is no error.
- Deleted current migration files and Snapshot file, still did not work

[image]

Both work, I debugged them.

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options) { }
    public ApplicationDbContext()
    {
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
            .Build();

        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
        base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
    }

    // Here are all the DbSet<> like this:
    public DbSet<MyEntity> MyEntities => Set<MyEntity>();
}

public class DesignTimeDbContextFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<ApplicationDbContext>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
    {
        var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                        .SetBasePath(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory)
                        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
                        .Build();
        var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ApplicationDbContext>();
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));

        return new ApplicationDbContext(optionsBuilder.Options);
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

In order to get it to run, I have reallocated the `ApplicationDbContext` in its own project.
My luck is that I already had the Enities in a own project :)

Other wise I would had to reallocate them too :(

Comment: Have you tried using the dotnet commant line? From memory something like `dotnet ef migrations add MyMigration`

Comment: Yes, I did that too.

Comment: When it was working, Did you have ``DesignTimeDbContextFactory`` before?

Comment: I did not have it.
I managed to get it to work with an older branch. But it does not work every time. I have to delete all obj and bin folders in the solution directory to get it to run.
Yesterday i checked all branches after the one i got to work. But couldn't identify where the problem could be